# How to replace a specific occurrence of a sub-string in a string and ignoring incomplete matches in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

In my application I'm giving dictionary word suggestions and replacing the selected word with the suggested word using .replaceAll(). However that is replacing every sub string in the entire string

for example in this String,

```
String sentence = "od and not odds as a sample sam. but not odinary";
```

If I suggest the first word as **odd** .replaceAll() will replace every occurrence of **od** with **odd** hence affecting the fourth word to **oddds** and changing the sentence to

```
sentence.replaceAll("od", "odd");



//sentence String becomes
sentence ="odd and not oddds as a sample sam. but not oddinary"
```

Replacing the **od** to **odd** has affected all the other words which have the **od** characters in them.

Can any one help me with a better aproach?

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear - it would really help if you'd give a *code* example rather than just describing it. Show us code, sample input, actual output and expected output.

Comment: Some code snipped would be good to help you out.

Comment: why not include space as well ? `.replaceAll("od ","odd ")`

Comment: This will fail on the sentence: "My, this is od!"

Comment: @Amit.rk3, because that will include 'cod ', 'sod ', etc. You need to account for both spaces if any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use regex. For you example "\bod\b" will just match od as a whole word. \b is a word boundary, meaning either the start or the end of a word (whether it ends with a dot or a whitespace or anything else).

The replaceAll method can already take in a regex, but if you need more power you can look at the Matcher class.

```
String REPLACE_WORD = "od"
sentence.replaceAll("\\b" + REPLACE_WORD + "\\b", "odd");
```

will give you the correct answer. The \ tells java that you want to write \ instead of \b (it first parses the string, and than parses that string as regex).

Comment: Easily the best solution made for this exact case.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular expression in the `replaceAll()` method:

```
\bod\b
```

This will filter out occurrences of the `od` inside any other word.
Of course when you use it in Java method, you need to escape the `\`

So

```
replaceAll("\\bod\\b", "odd");
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can use a `Matcher` from `Java.util.regex.*` which has a lot of useful functionality.

```
String text = "I detect quite an od odour.";
String searchTerm = "\\bod\\b";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(searchTerm);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

text = matcher.replaceAll("odd");

System.out.println(text);
```

The output would be:

> I detect quite an odd odour.